# cant add Web User Control (vs 2010)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In my project, solution explorer I click on the folder and -> add new Item. I would like to add web user control but I cant see it. In previous versions of visual studio I didnt have such a problem,

any idead on how can I add this template ?

thanks for any help,
Bye

EDIT:

this is how it looks:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/controlka.png/

in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033

I dont have any web zip files :/

But when I create new WebSite or asp.net Web Application tempaltes are available.

Project Im working on is converted from vs2008

Comment: what type of project did you create it as?

Comment: now its class library. In drop down I have windows application and console application to choose

Answer (score 0):

- Is your project set for Client Profile in your project's properties? If so, change it not to.
- Is Web selected in the tree to the right?

Comment: how can I change it to Client Profile ?

Comment: Check in your project properties.